# Add a teams-calendar to outlook

Tags: outlook, microsoft-teams, outlook-calendar

In microsoft teams I created a new team and added a new tab - the channel calendar.

And now my aim is to include this teams channel calendar to my outlook. Older teams calendars are already added to Outlook group calendars, but I don't really find a hint how to solve this issue.

So I hope you can give me an approach to include my teams channel calendar to my outlook.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A channel calendar can be added to Outlook, but by default hidden. You need to use PowerShell to make this group calendar visible in outlook. This one will show events created in all channels of the team.

Please refer:

Connect to Exchange Powershell module and run the following command:
Set-UnifiedGroup -Identity MyTeam -HiddenFromExchangeClientsEnabled:$False

An example guide here:

https://olafd.wordpress.com/2018/10/13/make-microsoft-teams-team-visible-in-outlook/

Official doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/set-unifiedgroup?view=exchange-ps